# an error in R code written for finding clusters

Tags: r, k-means, data-science

I am relatively new to R. I just try to find out optimum number of clusters for iris data using the following methods:

```
library(datasets)
head(iris)

# method1:
wss <- (nrow(iris)-1)*sum(apply(iris,2,var))
  for (i in 2:3) wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(iris,                           centers=i)$withinss)
plot(1:3, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters",ylab="Within groups sum of squares")

# method2:
library(fpc)
pamk.best <- pamk(iris)
cat("number of clusters estimated by optimum average silhouette width:", pamk.best$nc, "\n")
plot(pam(iris, pamk.best$nc))
```

Both methods throw up error. So please do someone shed light on it. Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: When getting error message you should include the exact error message in your question. Did you look at the result of `apply(iris,2,var)`? That might give you a clue as to what's going on. You can't use kmeans on categorical (factor) data directly.

Comment: Has nothing to do with the programming: I think your criterion for the optimum number of clusters for kmeans shouldn't be the the minimum of the withinss, because that will reduce every time you add a cluster, until every observation is one cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apply(iris,2,var)
```

gives you an error because the 4th column is not numeric.
Try
`apply(iris[,1:4],2,var)`

The same goes for the second method.

```
Error in pam(sdata, k, diss = diss, ...) : 
  x is not a numeric dataframe or matrix.
```